# Probability that a 2-d random variable falls into an area equals the double integral of its PDF?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, random-variables, random

Let $x:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a 2-dimensional r.v., and $f(p,q)$ be its probability density function.

For what kind of $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathrm{Pr}[x\in D]=\iint_D f(p,q)\mathrm{d}p\mathrm{d}q$ ?

I couldn't find a proof for this from the definition of r.v., even in the most simple case of $D=\{(x,y)|x,y\geq 0,x+y\leq1\}$ (perhaps it's just me being stupid). (okay, now I see that this can be proven using the definition of integration, by splitting D into rectangles.but can this be applied to general D or is there a more elegant proof?)

Comment: I would look again at the definition of "pdf", for a hint.

Comment: Erm - Is this not the *definition* of a probability density function?

Comment: According to the version I saw, pdf is defined as something becoming the cumulative density function after integration, which obviously implies the proposition in question **with D being a rectangle**.  The general case seem not that obvious. And if in some other version pdf is defined with general D, the question falls to why such definition is consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question for measure theory; I will use the basics of that subject freely in the answer.  It may be possible to redo the proof using Riemann integration if $f$ is Riemann integrable (and attention is restricted to Riemann integrable sets $D$), but I haven't tried writing the details yet.

Let $\mu$ be the law of $x$.  In other words, $\mu$ is the Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined by
\begin{align*}
\mu(D) = \mathbb{P}\{x \in D\}.
\end{align*}

We know that if $D$ is a rectangle of the form $[a,b) \times [c,d)$, then $\mu(D) = \int_{D} f(p,q) \, dp \, dq$.

I claim that this determines $\mu$, that is, that $\mu(D) = \int_{D} f(p,q) \, dp \, dq$ for each Borel set $D$.

To see this, let $\mathscr{B}$ be the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.  First, I claim that $\mathscr{B} = \sigma(\mathcal{D})$, where $\mathcal{D} = \{[a,b) \times [c,d) \, \mid \, a,b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}\}$.  To see this, notice that if $\mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is open, then we can find open rectangles $\{[a_{n},b_{n}) \times [c_{n},d_{n}) \, \mid \, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ with $\{(a_{n},b_{n},c_{n},d_{n}) \, \mid \, n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}^{4}$ such that $\mathcal{O} = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} [a_{n},b_{n}) \times [c_{n},d_{n})$.  (Here I'm using the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.)  Hence $\sigma(\mathcal{D})$ contains all the open sets, which implies it contains $\mathscr{B}$.  Conversely, $\mathscr{B} \supseteq \mathcal{D}$ so $\mathscr{B}$ contains $\sigma(\mathcal{D})$.

Next, note that the following statement is an elementary consequence of Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem:

> If $\mu_{1},\mu_{2}$ are two Borel probability measures on a
> measurable space $(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathscr{B})$, then $\mu_{1} =
>  \mu_{2}$ if and only if $\mu_{1}(D) = \mu_{2}(D)$ independently of the
> choice of $D \in \mathcal{D}$.

Here I am using the fact that $\mathcal{D}$ is a $\pi$-system (finite intersections of rectangles are rectangles again) and the set $\{D \in \mathscr{B} \, \mid \, \mu_{1}(D) = \mu_{2}(D)\}$ is a $\lambda$-system (since $\mu_{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2}) = \mu_{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2}) = 1$).

Applying this with $\mu_{1} = \mu$ and $\mu_{2}(D) = \int_{D} f(p,q) \, dp \, dq$ and $\mathcal{A}$ the smallest algebra containing $\mathcal{D}$, we conclude that $\mu(D) = \int_{D} f(p,q) \, dp \, dq$ for all Borel sets $D$.